# Unity Referencing gameobjects in script in prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

Is there any way how to reference a game `GameObject`, `Canvas`, `SpriteRenderer` using code?

To give some context I now have a mechanic for randomly generating `GameObject`s (lakes and stuff) out of **prefabs**. Each prefab has a script attached to it

[image: this ->]

But I need to make it so each reference gets filled on the objects spawn.

I have managed to find a way how to do that with scripts

```
public static FishingMiniGame Instance { get; private set; }
```

and then

```
FishingMiniGameScript = FishingMiniGame.Instance;
```

but I cant find a way how to reference other things pls help.

I expect the solution to be something with `GameObject.Find` but if so I would need to find a way to do the same for `SpriteRenderer`s because there is no such thing as `SpriteRenderer.Find` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use GameObject.Find to get the parent object of the sprite renderer and then from there get the child sprite renderer("MyObjectName");

```
GameObject myObject = GameObject.Find("MyObjectName");
SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = myObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the most obvious would be

```
var someSpriteRenderer = GameObject.Find("XY").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
```

Nothing hinders you from doing that - except I would discourage it (see bottom).

---

For single instance existing components you could also use [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html).

Again I would discourage even that.

---

In general your solution with the static property is half of the [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

To complete this you would actually have to ensure

- that only one instance exists

  e.g. like

  ```
  private void Awake()
  {
      if(Instance && Instance != this)
      {
          Destroy(gameObject);
          return;
      }

      Instance = this;
  }
  ```
- that there exists at least one instance.

  Most of the time not really feasible in Unity because you can't simply create the instance as it requires some configuration and references adjusted in the Inspector etc (unless you use some sort of dependency injection - in which case your question wouldn't be relevant though ;) ). Of course there are some dirty workarounds for this but not really worth the trouble so most of the time you actually would skip this part.

However, in general this pattern is very controversial as it is lazy blocks modularization/encapsulation as it has hard dependency links. Therefore this shouldn't really be used.

`FindObjectOfType` btw kind of goes into the same direction as a singleton just a bit from another perspective.

---

Instead, something is actually spawning your prefabs (= calling `Instantiate`). This thing most probably lives somewhere in the scene as the spawning is triggered by something happening in the scene

=> Why does that thing that spawns your instances not simply already have all the references to the other scene objects that are required by your prefab instances and injects them into the thing it just spawned?

On your prefabs the script would not expose the fields but rather implement e.g.

```
private Canvas fishingMiniGameCanvas;
private GameObject interactWindow;
private FishingMiniGame fishingMiniGameScript;
private Timer timer;
private GameObject rybaWindow;
private SpriteRenderer rybaSpriteRenderer;

public void Initialize(Canvas fishingMiniGameCanvas, GameObject interactWindow, FishingMiniGame fishingMiniGameScript, Timer timer, GameObject rybaWindow, SpriteRenderer rybaSpriteRenderer)
{
    this.fishingMiniGameCanvas = fishingMiniGameCanvas;
    this.interactWindow = interactWindow;
    this.fishingMiniGameScript = fishingMiniGameScript;
    this.timer = timer;
    this.rybaWindow = rybaWindow;
    this.rybaSpriteRenderer = rybaSpriteRenderer;
}
```

and then where you spawn these you expose them via Inspector and inject those reference after creating an

```
[SerializeField] private FishingEvent prefab;

[Header("SceneReferences")]
[SerilaizeField] private Canvas fishingMiniGameCanvas;
[SerializeField] private GameObject interactWindow;
// actually this one could even reference and provide the Canvas
// acting as a single central channel for other related references
[SerilaizeField] private FishingMiniGame fishingMiniGameScript;
[SerializeField] private Timer timer;
[SerializeField] private GameObject rybaWindow;
[SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer rybaSpriteRenderer;

private FishingEvent SpawnFishingEvent()
{
    var instance = Instantiate(prefab); 
    instance.Initialize(fishingMiniGameCanvas, interactWindow, fishingMiniGameScript, timer, rybaWindow, rybaSpriteRenderer);
}
```

Imho, that would be way cleaner architecture design wise, and way less error prone and easy to maintain as it happens in a central place and doesn't require/rely on hard coded strings.